# Difference between @objc before class and @objc(class_name) above class in swift?

Tags: swift, class

What's the difference between :

```
@objc class MyClass: NSObject{}
```

and

```
@objc(MyClass)
class MyClass: NSObject{}
```

Comment: It's redundant in both cases. `MyClass` inherits from `NSObject` - an ObjC class so `@objc` is already added for you.

Comment: @ZoffDino If you remove NSObject, Xcode will display the error "Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@objc` modifier is being deprecated in Swift 2. All classes that were marked as `@objc` have to be a subclass of `NSObject`, thus making the modifier `@objc` redundant.

`@objc(xxx)`, however, is used to define an alternative name for the class (to be used by the runtime and from Objective-C code).

This modifier is only useful if you want a different name to use in your runtime / Objective C code.

By default the runtime name is same as the declared name, **prefixed by the module name and a dot**. For example, `class X: NSObject {}` would be `@objc(MyModule.X)` at runtime.

Comment: So it's recommended that changing the code from  `@objc class MyClass: NSObject{}`  to `class MyClass: NSObject{}`, right?  If we don't add `@objc(xxx)` above the class, this class can't be used by the runtime, e.g it can't be used by NSClassFromString().

Comment: thanks your reply. As your comment it should be same if we use `@objc(SameClassName)` and `class SameClassName: NSObject`. But when I use `NSClassFromString`, `@objc(SameClassName)` works, the other one is failed.

Comment: @pyanfield updated again. Hopefully this clears everything up.

Comment: if we use `@objc(xxx)` modifier we can use the `xxx` as the class name for `NSClassFromString` directly. If not we should add the module name with class name. It makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it on a separate line or not. That is entirely up to you.

If you use `@objc(SomeOtherName)`, it tells the compiler to make the class accessible from Objective-C code using the name `SomeOtherName` instead of the Swift class name (which might not have an Objective-C equivalent).